# Where do I post a question about IP-network and game hosting?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to host a game on my computer (Starcraft broodwar) but I have problems setting up the network (I already have a static IP and firewall allowing the game).

Is there SE website where I could ask a question like that so I figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask about networking/firewall/port forwarding questions in general on [Super User](http://superuser.com). If the problem's exclusive to Starcraft: Broodwar, [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) is a better choice.